# Mocking Class Functions

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to unittest a class which has a decently complicated __init__, one involving calls to servers and external components. I found that you can use the unittest MagicMock to fake an init.

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.var = arg1
        self.method1(arg2)

    def method1(self, arg):
        var = "Hello " + arg
        self.method2(var)

    def method2(self, var):
        print(var)

SELF = MagicMock()
my_calss.my_class.__init__(SELF, arg1, arg2)
```

Which is awesome cause all the code which talks with a server is in other methods and I can make sure that the __init__ calls certain methods.

The problem comes when I want test a method which calls another method.

```
SELF = MagicMock()
my_class.__init__(SELF, arg1, arg2)
SELF.method2 = my_class.method2
my_class.method1(SELF, arg)
```

I'd expect the self in method2 to be SELF but method2 never gets a self.
Is there a way of insuring that method2 gets the mocked SELF?

Or another method of testing class methods that doesn't involve a ton of patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to achieve that with `MagicMock`.

One approach would be to use the `__new__` classmethod to create an instance of your class without calling its `__init__` method, then configure its properties in the test setup as needed.

For example

```
instance = my_class.__new__(my_class)
# Manually initialize properties as needed.
instance.usually_set_by_init = 3

# Use the instance like normal.
instance.method1(arg)
```

If you haven't heard of `__new__` this can seem weird, but it's helpful to realize that `a = A()` is equivalent to `a = A.__new__(A); a.__init__()`.

Comment: So there is no way of adding methods to a Mock object?

Comment: You could, but the above approach will cause significantly less headaches

Answer (score 0):

You can just stub out the class instead of mocking.

`class MyClassStub(MyClass):
  def __init__(self):
    pass # bypass parents init`